# Django Carton, changing the cart.add() function so that I can add options for products

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm creating a website that will have product that people can order. I decided to go with Carton as a shopping cart. I can see that the cart.add() function only takes the product, price and quantity. The products I have on the page allow for choices in colour, quality and a variable price. I got the variables into the view, but when adding into the:

`cart.add(product, price, quantity)`

I cannot add anymore arguments for the options:

`cart.add(product, price, quantity, options)`

when I do, I get an error saying there can only be 2-4 arguments. anyone who worked with this before, found a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's `Carton`? Is that a 3rd party library or did you write it yourself?

Comment: It’s a third party shopping cart app. I didn’t write it myself, it was written by lazybird a while ago